# Does God really exist or Its just psychological concept

Tags: gods, philosophy

Does **God** really exists physically, virtually or in any form?

or

Is **God** just a term intelligently used for psychological satisfaction and for making our life easy?

Comment: It's the latter. According to the [Carvaka-Lokayata school](http://www.iep.utm.edu/indmat/) of philosophy, there is no such thing as god/gods/God/soul or after-life.